# Is there anyway to calculate pearson correlation having inputs as theano tensors?

Tags: statistics, theano

scipy.stats package provides a function for calculating pearson coefficient with numpy array. But is there a library with which we can pass theano tensors as input and calculate the correlation. Eval() function is option to convert the tensors to values but that is not possible to do during run time of a code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The centered cosine similarity is the same as the Pearson correlation.
In theano it can be computed as follows:

```
a = T.vector(dtype=theano.config.floatX)
b = T.vector(dtype=theano.config.floatX)

a_centered, b_centered = a - a.mean(), b - b.mean()
r_num = T.dot(a_centered, b_centered)
r_den = T.sqrt(T.dot(a_centered, a_centered) * T.dot(b_centered, b_centered))

# written without the dot products for pedagogical reasons
# r_num = T.sum(a_centered * b_centered)
# r_den = T.sqrt(T.sum(a_centered ** 2) * T.sum(b_centered ** 2))

pearson_corr = r_num / r_den
pearson_corr_fn = theano.function([a, b], pearson_corr)

v1 = np.asarray([3, 4, 5, 7], dtype=np.float32)
v2 = np.asarray([2, 5, 3, 1], dtype=np.float32)

print pearson_corr_fn(v1, v2)
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer if it is what you want; otherwise let us know what you need.